# Validation Rules not fired on Approval

Tags: validation, validation-rule, approval-process

I am having few validation rules on Opportunity, which should be fired when `StageName` is `"Closed Won"`. An example validation rule is shown below

```
AND (
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won'), ISBLANK( SomeOppField__c )
)
```

> Opportunity > StageName = "Closed Won" happens after Approval > Field Update.

Somehow none of the validation rule fires after Opportunity is approved to closed won, my requirement is to block approval process, if data on opportunity is missing.

Comment: `Closed-won` and `Approved` are two entirely different things. If you're moving to `Closed-won` as part of your Approval process, then you likely need to separate the two. I don't believe you can have a validation rule fire on an approval process. That runs under an entirely different context than when a typical user saves a record.

Answer (score 2):

Workflow rule field updates (and hence by association, Approval Process field updates) don't fire Validation Rules. [Per the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_validation_considerations.htm&language=nl)

> Because updates to records based on workflow rules don’t trigger
>   validation rules, workflow rules can invalidate previously valid
>   fields.

The reason for this is that time-based workflow actions and approval processes don't really have any mechanism for catching errors and asking the user to resolve them.  So, SFDC takes the view that it is your job to make sure that you design workflows and approval processes to not run into errors (in your case, cueing the user to not even submit the record for approval if the object is in some state)