# How to make an Object be in Read-only mode

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, approval-process

I want my Opportunity object to go into Read-only mode, so that no one can edit old records and create new ones.

I activated a validation rule with the formula "ISNEW()||NOT(ISNEW())". With this I am unable to edit records and create new ones. But my Problem is that an Approval Process is activated for this object; and when the Approval Process is triggered, it is changing the Status (Custom) field. I don't want that to happen. I want to have the same message ("this object is in Read-Only mode") as in the case of the Validation rule.

What is the way forward?

Comment: When I click "Submit for Approval", I have an Initial Submission action of changing the status field. then I want to pop-up the error message

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [Validation Rules not fired on Approval](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113385/validation-rules-not-fired-on-approval), validation rules won't trigger on approval processes.

However, [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) can be used. Here's the minimal code required to block editing Cases entirely:

```java
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before update) {
    for (Case record : Trigger.new) {
        record.addError('You can\'t edit cases');
    }
}
```